# can this this strlen argument be used for validation?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. My problem is I need the input to validate to a minimum 20 character input and return the last nine. Can anybody tell me if my argument is close to working and if not what do I need to do?

```
if (!empty($_POST['usen']) ||
    strlen($usen['usen'] >= 20 )) {  
    $switch = substr($usen, -9, 9); // returns last nine of sentence
    $output_form=false;
} else {
     $error_text .="<p><span class='error'>*<strong>A Sentence of 20 char is required .</strong></span></p>"; 
     $output_form=true; 
}
```

Comment: Well, *is* it working? If not, what's wrong? Please try to narrow down this question and explain what you need help with.

Comment: Also, here's a hint: it's very unlikely you mean to check `empty($_POST['usen'])` and then try to use `$usen['usen']` and `$usen`. Pretty sure those should be `$_POST['usen']`, as well.

Comment: its not working the right way, if I enter less than 20 characters it outputs (should throw an error), if I enter 20 or more characters it outputs  as it should. the substr works as it should I just cannot get it to throw the error msg when I have less than 20 characters

Comment: And did you try making the fixes I suggested in my second comment?

Comment: Tip: Trim your data before applying _strlen_ function to it, `strlen(trim(_POST['usen']))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several syntax problems and variable-naming problems. Your code *should* be:

```
if (!empty($_POST['usen']) && // || should be &&; the || doesn't make sense here
    strlen($_POST['usen']) >= 20 ) { // You had $usen['usen'] and an incorrectly placed ) 
    $switch = substr($_POST['usen'], -9); // again, this should be $_POST['usen'], not $usen. The third parameter is unnecessary here.
    $output_form = false;
} else {
    $error_text .= "<p><span class='error'>*<strong>A Sentence of 20 char is required .</strong></span></p>"; 
    $output_form = true; 
}
```

The key points:

- You're using the wrong boolean operator. `!empty($x) || strlen($x) >= 20` doesn't make sense. It should be `&&`, not `||`. If you have a non-empty value for `$_POST['usen']`, then `!empty($_POST['usen'])` is `true`. But because you had a `||` in your `if` conditional, this meant the `if` block always executed for non-empty values, never the `else` block. You only want the `if` to execute if the value is non-empty *and* at least 20 characters.
- Your variable is `$_POST['usen']`, but your code referred to `$usen['usen']` and `$usen`, which are incorrect.
- You had `strlen($usen['usen'] >= 20)` where you should have `strlen($_POST['usen']) >= 20`. Both the variable name and the `)` placement were incorrect.

Comment: Hi Ed, I made the recommended changes, still I can only get the error msg if I leave the input field empty and submit, then the error msg works, if I have less than 20 characters inputed, I dont receive the error msg and data outputs.

Comment: @BillyPayne See my edit; there was another error I missed, namely the incorrect boolean operator. If you have a non-empty value for `$_POST['usen']`, then `!empty($_POST['usen'])` is `true`. Because you had a `||` in your `if` conditional, this meant the `if` block always executed for non-empty values, never the `else` block.

Comment: that is correct, thanks for expert knowledge, I have learned so much from this one mistake and will never forget it, thanks again!

Comment: @BillyPayne Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the last 9 characters of $usen['usen'] use

```
$switch = substr($usen, -9);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_POST['usen']) ||
   strlen($_POST['usen']) >= 20 ) {  // changed condition 
 $switch = substr($usen, -9, 9); // returns last nine of sentence
 $output_form=false;

} else {
 $error_text .="<p><span class='error'>*<strong>A Sentence of 20 char is required .</strong></span></p>"; 
 $output_form=true; 
}
```

The if-condition has two issues in second part

1. You use `$usen['usen']` but i think it schould be `$_POST['usen']` (see also comment by `@Ed Cottrell`)
2. The closing bracker from method-call strlen has to be after the param

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_POST['usen']) &&
    strlen($_POST['usen'] )>= 20 ) {  //condition change
    $switch = substr($_POST['usen'] ,-9); // returns last nine of sentence
    $output_form=false;
} else {
     $error_text .="<p><span class='error'>*<strong>A Sentence of 20 char is required .</strong></span></p>"; 
     $output_form=true; 
}
```

To get last 9 charcters , you can use substr(string, -9);

Comment: This is the working answer, && instead of || made it work, Thanks everyone for all your help!